# Find last row per each column of a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the following `dataframe` and I want to get a vector that contains the last `non-NA` row of each column:

```
df <- data.frame(a = 1:5, b = 6:10, c = c(rep(NA, 5)))
df <- rbind(df, rep(NA, ncol(df)), rep(NA, ncol(df)))
df[2,] <- NA
df$b[6]<-8

df
   a  b  c
1  1  6 NA
2 NA NA NA
3  3  8 NA
4  4  9 NA
5  5 10 NA
6 NA  8 NA
7 NA NA NA
```

The vector I am looking for would be as follows:

```
c(5,6,0)
```

How can I achieve this using **`base R`**? So far, I run the following formula...

```
apply(row(df) + 0 * df, 2, function(x) max(x, na.rm = TRUE))
```

...but it throws me the following warning message:

`Warning message: In max(x, na.rm = TRUE) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf`

Comment: `max.col(t(rbind(0, row(df) * !is.na(df))), ties.method = "first") - 1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```r
sapply(df, function(z) c(rev(which(!is.na(z))), 0)[1])
# a b c 
# 5 6 0
```

Answer (score 3):

Another incantation via `Position`, looking from the `right=`/end, for a non-NA (`Negate(is.na)`) value, returning a `0L` if `nomatch` found.

```
sapply(df, Position, f=Negate(is.na), right=TRUE, nomatch=0L)
#a b c 
#5 6 0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `match` like so:

```r
f <- function(x) {
    if (n <- length(x)) n + 1L - match(FALSE, is.na(x)[n:1L], n + 1L) else 0L
}

sapply(df, f)
## a b c 
## 5 6 0
```

Answer (score 0):

An option with `colMaxs`

```
library(matrixStats)
colMaxs(row(df) * !is.na(df))
[1] 5 6 0
```